# Struts2 Global Exception - Original Exception Source

Tags: java, configuration, exception, struts2, stack-trace

I'm using global exception mapping in Struts 2 as follows:

```xml
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
</global-exception-mappings>

<!-- ******* ACTIONS ******  -->
<action name="timeout" class="errorAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="carsBasic" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
<result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The flow is perfect but I'd like to know how to obtain which Action (and hopefully method) that threw the exception.

in the `timeOut` action class, execute method, it correctly adds an `actionMessage` indicating 'an error' but in here I'd like to add code that is logged/emailed to me to show the offending class and method.

Is this stored somewhere and how may I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log exception you need to use some logger like log4j. There's some appender that allows to send email could be configured.

When exception occured and handled by the `exception` interceptor it stores the values to the value stack. The values are stored:

> - `exception`: The exception object itself
> - `exceptionStack`: The value from the stack trace

You can configure the action that will handle the exception and log these values retrieving them from the value stack, and configure a global result to execute when exception is handled. This result could be of type `chain` where the values of previous action are in the value stack of the next action.

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="exception" type="chain">ExceptionAction</result>
</global-results>
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  It was the 'chain' result type as you saw was missing that lost all the info I needed.